# How to dynamically populate materialize material_chip data and add extra data to chips?

Tags: javascript, materialize

I would like to have several chip inputs on page, each of these fields has a separate list of tags. Also I want the tags to carry some extra data in them like the id of the referenced object (more on this later).

To figure out what tag list should be used for each of the chips inputs I wanted to use the actual input, i.e.:

```
<div class="chips" data-taglist-id="10"></div>
<div class="chips" data-taglist-id="21"></div>
```

data-taglist-id is of course the index in some array of tags, i.e.:

```
var tags = [
    0: [...],
    [...]
    10: [{tag: 'one'}, {tag: 'two'}],
    [...]
    21: [{tag: 'another'}, {tag: 'different'}]
];
```

so instead of delivering array to materialize_chips like that:

```
$('.chips').material_chip({
    data: tags[0]
});
```

I'd like something like that (code below is just for illustration as it does not work):

```
$('.chips').material_chip({
    data: function(this) {
       var taglistId = $(this).data('taglist-id');
       return tags[taglistId];
    }
});
```

Another thing - I would like each tag in the chips to have some data attribute(s), so instead of being an entry like this:

```
<div class="chip">Apple<i class="material-icons close">close</i></div>
```

to be:

```
<div class="chip" data-object-id="123">Apple<i class="material-icons close">close</i></div>
```

The idea is to add some extra info to tags array like that:

```
[...]
10: [{tag: 'one', data: { object-id: 123} }, {tag: 'two', data: {object-id: 234}}],
[...]
```

and then add this to chips > div.chip while generating the entries...

Since I got stuck on the first problem I did not get to this yet but just wanted to ask - the only way to implement that would be to extend the material_chip by myself?

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: Just an update: after looking into the material_chip plugin source I cannot figure out a way to extend it, so I just "forked" it and did the changes to add support for data tags etc. If anyone can provide better idea for doing it (or extending that plugin) that would be great.